# Array of arrays with different data types

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a map based web application.I am not able to create the location data which is a array containing the arrays in the below format in plain java code.(array containing arrays ).The inner array should be having first and second element as double and the third as String.

```
var LocationData = [
        [12.3, 77.1, "ABDC" ], 
        [12.4, 77.3, "PQRS" ],
        [12.6, 77.4, "XYZA" ]
    ];
```

It is like we need to populate the map markers in the maps.The javascript data above is the location specific data.Somehow I need to pass the data in the above format from the spring controller.Advise needed if this can be send it as JSON string or if the data in the above format can be obtained in plain java code

Regards.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this as Java?  That looks more like Javascript to me.

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Your code sample is JavaScript, and you talk about a web-based application... Now of course, Java can be the server-side of a web-based app, but...

Comment: Create a "Bean" or Class (data structure) with relevant attributes then store instances of the class in an array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: My mistake missed out to mention the full use case.It is like we need to populate the map markers in the maps.The javascript data above is the location specific data.Somehow I need to pass the data in the above format from the spring controller.Advise needed if this can be send it as JSON string or if the data in the above format can be obtained in plain java code.

Comment: @DavidWallace:I missed out to mention the full use case.

Answer (score 5):

You should create a POJO for this as its a more OO approach. Here's a very simple snippet:

```
class MyData {
   private double first;
   private double second;
   private String str;

   //constructors using fields, getter, setter, equals, hashCode, etc.
}
```

Then just create an array of MyData objects.

```
 MyData[] array = new MyData[3];
 array[0] = new MyData(12.3, 77.1, "ABDC");
 ...
```

Comment: I'm getting upvoted but reading the comments, I also have the feeling that the OP wants to do this in Javascript. I'm not an expert in JS but you could also do the same kind of thing.

Comment: Even assuming that OP wants a Java solution, you need to add a WHOLE lot more to this to make it work.  This might be a useful answer if it weren't so terribly incomplete.  -1, sorry, and scratching my head over the 3 upvotes.

Comment: @DavidWallace You are right, I updated it. I think the OP would be able to do this by itself now, without writing all the code.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer with OO approach is the best way. For some reason if you can't use that, you can use the array of objects.

```
    Object obj1[] = {1,1.2,"test"};
    Object obj2[] = {1,1.2,"test"};
    Object obj3[] = {obj1,obj2};
```